# How do I separate the matches between two columns into a column of their own?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing inventory at work, basically  I have 2 columns of data: one is what is expected to be here, and one column is what I've found. I'm trying to set it up where I can compare the two columns and then have those that are found either be moved to a different column (preferably), or be sorted to the top so it'd show the found and not found separately. I'm currently using *=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A1)=0, "No match in B", "")* to check what's there/not there, but this gives the answers out of order. Please help if able and thank you in advance. :)

Edit:

My actual table is almost 4k rows so here is an example.

apple   apple
bananna grape
orange  lime
kiwi    lemon
grape   orange

| found | expected |
| --- | --- |
| apple | apple |
| orange | grape |
| orange | lime |
| grape | lemon |
| grape | orange |

I'd need the formula to check if column A has a match in column B (which I already have working). And then I want to have the ones that DO have a match, have that row in column A be moved to a separate column/table (basically so I can send what we have)

Comment: If column A lists a value twice and B once, would you list only one from A, or two? And what if both list it twice? Would you want the unique matches, or also list duplicates?

Comment: Also, do you have Office 365?

Comment: Sorry had a meeting and a fire drill :) Yes I'd only list it once, the second list doesn't have duplicates so it shouldn't be an issue. Though if there's a type of safeguard to put in place if that does happen then sure. Only unique matches would be ideal. Yes I can use excel or google sheets, I like sheets better but either is fine.

Comment: See posted answer. Sheets would work differently. The reason I asked if you have Office 365 is that functions like `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` do not exist in prior Excel versions.

Answer (score 0):

When using Office 365 you could use `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,COUNTIF(B2:B6,A2:A6)))`

Older versions can use and copy down `=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,MATCH($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,0)+1,ROW(A1))),"")` array function needs entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

This provides the unique distinct values that occur in the range of column B.
`+1` behind the match result is because we start searching from row 2, therefore the match result will represent the row # minus 1. `+1` corrects this.